# Constructing a quotient ring in GAP using structure constants

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gap

I need to construct the following ring in GAP:

$$Z_4(u) / \langle u^2-2u=0 \rangle. $$

This is what I tried and it didn't work:

```
gap> R:=PolynomialRing(Integers mod 4,"u");AssignGeneratorVariables(R);
<monoid>[u]
#I  Global variable `u' is already defined and will be overwritten
#I  Assigned the global variables [ u ]
gap> I:=Ideal(R,[u^2-2*u]);
<two-sided ideal in <monoid>[u], (1 generators)>
gap> A:=R/I;
Error, no method found! For debugging hints type ?Recovery from        
NoMethodFound
Error, no 3rd choice method found for `NaturalHomomorphismByIdeal' on 2
arguments called from NaturalHomomorphismByIdeal( A, I ) called from
<function "unknown">( <arguments> )
called from read-eval loop at line 15 of *stdin*
you can 'quit;' to quit to outer loop, or
you can 'return;' to continue
brk>
```

Does anyone know how to construct this ring in GAP?

Thanking you in advance!

Comment: I downvoted because of the bad formatting. Please see instructions on how to use MathJax: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Looks much better after editing, thanks! I'd advice to make names of your three questions more distinguishable - that may be helpful to other users.

Comment: I've nominated this question for reopening - it looks similar to two other questions recently asked by @JoeG, but it requires different approach (using structure constants) so it is worth to keep it (though probably it would be better just to have one question with three different rings in it).

Answer (score 3):

The ideal quotient algorithms are only implemented for polynomial rings over fields. The only way to construct this ring would be by structure constants.

For example here you would have two generators ($a$ and $u$). The structure constant table encodes the multiplication of the generators

```
gap> T:=EmptySCTable(2,0);; # generators, zero coefficient
gap> SetEntrySCTable(T,1,1,[1,1]); # a*a=1*a (list is [coeff,gen,....
gap> SetEntrySCTable(T,1,2,[1,2]); # a*u=1*u
gap> SetEntrySCTable(T,2,1,[1,2]); # u*a=1*u
gap> SetEntrySCTable(T,2,2,[2,2]); # u*u=2*u
```

Both generators have additive order 4, and we want them to be printed as `a` and `u`

```
gap> r:=RingByStructureConstants([4,4],T,["a","u"]);
<ring with 2 generators>
gap> Elements(r);
[ 0*a, u, 2*u, -u, a, a+u, a+2*u, a-u, 2*a, 2*a+u, 2*a+2*u, 2*a-u, -a, -a+u, 
  -a+2*u, -a-u ]
```

Comment: Dear Professor Hulpke, thank you very much for your help so far. I am sorry to bother you again, but could you point me in the direction of an example of constructing rings using structure constraints.

Comment: @JoeG added example

Comment: I suppose the reason why the quotient of the ring $R := ZmodnZ(56);$ by the ideal $A := Ideal(R, [8]*o);$ where $o$ is  $One(R)$, also fails. But I don't see how to construct $\Bbb Z_{56}$ by a structure table, and how to extract the ideal $A$ from it.

Comment: @MarcBogaerts: You can construct $\mathbb{Z}/n$ using a single generator $e$ with the multiplicative relation $e * e = e$ and the additive relation $n \cdot e = 0$.