# Mysterious computation of a ring quotient in GAP

Tags: ring-theory, fake-proofs, computer-algebra-systems, gap

I want to do some calculations with finite rings in [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/). I have found a contradiction which I cannot explain.

How to create finite rings in GAP using structure constants is explained [here](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~hulpke/CGT/howtogap.pdf) on page 45; also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652379/). So in order to construct the example ring $\mathbb{Z}/2^n [X]/\langle X^2,2X \rangle$, I have written the following function in GAP:

```
ExampleRing := function(n)
local T,O;
T := EmptySCTable(2,0);       # 2 generators e,x as Z-module
O := [2^n,2];                 # ord(e)=2^n and ord(x)=2
SetEntrySCTable(T,1,1,[1,1]); # e*e = 1*e
SetEntrySCTable(T,1,2,[1,2]); # e*x = 1*x
SetEntrySCTable(T,2,1,[1,2]); # x*e = 1*x
SetEntrySCTable(T,2,2,[]);    # x*x = 0
return RingByStructureConstants(O,T,["e","x"]);
end;
```

Inside $\mathrm{ExampleRing}(4) = \mathbb{Z}/2^4 [X]/\langle X^2,2X \rangle$ consider the ideal $\langle 2^2 - X \rangle$. The quotient ring is $\mathbb{Z}/2^3$, right? But when I compute the quotient with GAP, it produces $\mathbb{Z}/4 [X]/\langle X^2,2X \rangle$ instead!

```
gap> R := ExampleRing(4);
<ring with 2 generators>
gap> AssignGeneratorVariables(R);
#I  Assigned the global variables [ e, x ]
gap> Q := R / Ideal(R,[2^2 * e - x]);
<ring with 2 generators>
gap> Elements(Q);
[ 0*q1, q2, q1, q1+q2, 2*q1, 2*q1+q2, -q1, -q1+q2 ]
gap> One(Q);
q1
gap> 4*One(Q);
0*q1
gap> AssignGeneratorVariables(Q);
#I  Assigned the global variables [ q1, q2 ]
gap> 2*q2;
0*q1
gap> q2^2;
0*q1
```

So either a) my code is wrong, b) my calculation of the quotient is wrong, or c) GAP's implementation is wrong. Could someone clarify this?

Also are there other computer algebra systems which can compute with finite rings of the form $\mathbb{Z}/n [X] / \langle X^2,a+bX \rangle$?

Edit: Apparently GAP's implementation is wrong or I do not use it correctly. Here is a very simple example: I define $\mathbb{Z}/8$ with structure constants and quotient out the ideal generated by $2$. This should be $\mathbb{Z}/2$, but GAP computes $\mathbb{Z}/4$:

```
gap> T := EmptySCTable(1,0);;
gap> SetEntrySCTable(T,1,1,[1,1]);
gap> R := RingByStructureConstants([8],T,["e"]);
<ring with 1 generators>
gap> AssignGeneratorVariables(R);
#I  Assigned the global variables [ e ]
gap> Elements(R);
[ 0*e, e, 2*e, 3*e, 4*e, 5*e, 6*e, -e ]
gap> e*e;
e
gap> I := Ideal(R,[2*e]);
<two-sided ideal in <ring with 1 generators>, (1 generators)>
gap> Elements(I);
[ 0*e, 2*e, 4*e, 6*e ]
gap> Q := R/I;
<ring with 1 generators>
gap> Elements(Q);
[ 0*q1, q1, 2*q1, -q1 ]
```

Comment: Did you check magma? I think there must something in it

Comment: @mayer_vietoris: I would like to try it, but it is not installed here, and it would be too expensive (http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/ordering/) to order it.

Comment: I see, you're right, I can try it for you if you want but from my office. And at the moment I'm not there :).

Comment: @mayer_vietoris: Thanks, that would be great.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg great, thanks for the bug report! In the future, if you suspect that you have found a bug, we will most appreciate if you could ubmit an issue at the GAP GitHub issue tracker here: https://github.com/gap-system/gap/issues

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: Ok, I will do so.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg 
By the way, you can run small programs on magma for free, at http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is two (stupid) bugs I will fix in the next release. Thank you for reporting.
I will put a temporary patch (just read in the file) at
https://www.dropbox.com/s/aprqfottc4pb6ni/quotringfix.g?dl=0

Apologies for the problem -- I would not be surprised if you are the first person actually using the code.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is amazing that you have promptly written a patch in order to address this issue. Here are some remaining questions: 1) Is it possible to install this patch permanently in my GAP system? 2) Did you mean that I am the first person who uses quotient rings applied to finite rings? 3) The second example with $\mathbb{Z}/8$ mod $2$ now works, but the first example $\mathrm{ExampleRing}(4)/\langle 2^2-X \rangle$ does not - at least not here. It produces the same ring as before. What goes wrong here?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Gern Geschehen. 1) You could put the file (or a `Read` command for the file) into your `gaprc` file. Send me an email if you'd like help with that. 2) I suspect. The code was written as basic functionality, but I'm not sure how much it got used. I'll write about 3) separately.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Indeed 3) was another bug -- the code assumed wrongly that generators of an ideal always aligned. I have updated the fix (first line gives 4/26 date to distinguish), with this the elements of `Q` in the first example are `[ 0*q1, q1, 2*q1, 3*q1, 4*q1, 5*q1, 6*q1, -q1 ]`. Apologies!

Comment: Thank you very much for the new code. It works now.